# jQuery mobile login, php, cookies not working

Tags: php, session, jquery-mobile, cookies, authentication

I'm building web app aas my major project for degree. Simple login was working but now I'm trying to implement cookies and my script is not working for some reason. I need to find out why, but can't do for last 2h. Here is my question:

From login form variables are passed into my login script (no security for password or jql injection was implemented so far), when I press login errors comes up, "Error Loading Page", this is login script:

```
session_start();

$username = $_GET["name"];
$password = $_GET["password"];
$remember_me = $_GET['remember_me'];

include('mysql_connection.php');
mysql_select_db("jzperson_imesUsers", $con);

$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
$count1=mysql_num_rows($res1);

if(isset($_COOKIE['usr_IMes']) && isset($_COOKIE['psw_IMes'])){
                    $user_n = $_COOKIE['usr_IMes'];
                    $pasw_n = $_COOKIE['psw_IMes'];

                    $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_login WHERE username='$user_n' AND password='$pasw_n'");
                    $count2=mysql_num_rows($res2);

                    if($count2 == 1){

                                    $_SESSION['username'] = $user_n;

                                    header('Location: http://imes,jzpersonal.com/userpanel.php');

                    }else {
                                    setcookie('usr_IMes', $user_n, time() - 31*24*60*60);
                            setcookie('psw_IMes', $pasw_n, time() - 31*24*60*60);

                                    header('Location: http://imes,jzpersonal.com/index.html');
                    }

}else{

if($count1==1){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    if(isset($remember_me)){

setcookie('usr_IMes', $username, time() + 30*24*60*60);
setcookie('psw_IMes', $password, time() + 30*24*60*60);

header("Location: http://imes.jzpersonal.com/userpanel.php");
    }else{      

      header("Location: http://imes.jzpersonal.com/userpanel.php");

   }
}else{
    $login = "failed";
}
}
```

Can anyone see problem in my script? In login part? If not here is my authentication script on the start of every page, maybe my error is there:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_COOKIE['usr_IMes']) && isset($_COOKIE['psw_IMes'])){
                    $user_n = $_COOKIE['usr_IMes'];
                    $pasw_n = $_COOKIE['psw_IMes'];

                    $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_login WHERE username='$user_n' AND password='$pasw_n'");
                    $count2=mysql_num_rows($res2);

                    if($count2 == 1){
                                    header('Location: http://imes,jzpersonal.com/userpanel.php');   
                    }else {
                                    setcookie('usr_IMes', $user_n, time() - 31*24*60*60);
                            setcookie('psw_IMes', $pasw_n, time() - 31*24*60*60);

                                    header('Location: http://imes,jzpersonal.com/index.html');
                    }

}else{

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
header('Location: http://imes.jzpersonal.com/index.html');
}

if(empty($_SESSION['username']))
{
header('Location: http://imes.jzpersonal.com/index.html');
}
}
```

Hope some error will be found, thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirect is a bad url: `http://imes,jzpersonal.com/userpanel.php` - this would give you your "error loading page". Besides that, you should NEVER store username/password in cookies - it is a terrible practice because cookies can be viewed on the machine. Also, you are using the original PHP MySQL API which is deprecated - you should be using PDO or mysqli.

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious from the answer, you need to change header('Location: ....'); to point to http://imes.jzpersonal.com/userpanel.php instead of the bad URL above.

Comment: it was, just didn't check it till morning, thank you for the help, and also a question. If I should never store username/password in cookies, what should I use? Should I store ID?

Comment: You should generate a unique token (like an md5 checksum of the date + a random number) and store that in a database table as well as in the cookie. You can match that token with the token in the database - and if they match the user is logged in. Make sure you set an expiration on both the database and cookie and give the user an option to "log out" which clears the token out of your database. You can easily find examples of this on Google and right here on SF.

Comment: With these scripts I was hoping to make cookies work, but I still can't make it. I was trying to echo $_COOKIE['usr_IMes'] and $_COOKIE['psw_IMes']. But it echoed nothing. So I think I'm setting up these variables wrong. Any chance you see from the code the problem?